# In Excel VBA, how do I open a PowerPoint slide and replace a text value?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

With the help of this community and my limited knowledge of coding VBA, I've written an Excel VBA macro which does the following; Scrubs a complex report, which then generates a Line Chart, and some key data points which I want to throw into a PowerPoint slide as a last step.

However I can't seem to get past opening my Slide. What I've done is create a template with the elements I want to replace. Here's a sample of the PowerPoint slide I have; I've selected all so you can see where my text boxes are.

[image: myTemplate.pptx]

This is a single slide, and what I want to do is replace say ":KE:" with a count of known errors.

Here is the code I have so far;

```
   Sub pptTest()

   Dim PowerPointApp As Object
   Dim myPresentation As Object
   Dim pptTemplate As String

   Dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape
   Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide


   pptTemplate = "c:\z_scripts\MyTemplate.pptx"

   Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

   Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(pptTemplate)

   'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
     PowerPointApp.Visible = True
     PowerPointApp.Activate

   Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(1)

   'Sample Data
   myKE = "6"

   myShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(myShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "KE", myKE)


   End Sub
```

This code opens my PowerPoint slide, but then complains about a With Block or Object variable not being set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set the `myShape` variable so it is `Nothing`. The error you get is equivalent to a null pointer exception

Comment: Actually had it there, but removed it while posting because it was causing another error. If I insert after;  ~~~ Set MySlide...~~~  this code; ~~~Set myShape = myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("KE")~~~ Then I get a "KE not found in shapes collection". I'm new to this level of coding, so please forgive me.

Comment: So you will have to reuse the instruction ```Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(zzz)```. But first you must identify which shape has to be modified. So, while debugging watch the content of ```mySlide.Shapes```. You will get the shape items and their ```Name```. It is then up to you to find in this list which one is the one you need to modify and replace zzz with this name

Comment: That did the trick. The main thing I was missing was; Set myShape = myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(6)  However, the trick was finding out what Shape index it was. So I wrote a PPT Macro which delete Shapes(1-8) Until I identified the correct shapes. Thanks for helping me move forward on this.